# Implementing an email server in java

Tags: java, mail-server

What all language components will have to be used for implementing an email service  system using java?

Comment: What sort of email server? SMTP? IMAP? POP?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to implement an email server (SMTP, IMAP, POP3) - there is already [Apache JAMES](http://james.apache.org/). It's open-source, so you can look into its sources if you insist on making one.

If you want to just send emails, having an already installed SMTP server, then use [Simple Java Mail](http://www.simplejavamail.org/) or [commons-email](http://commons.apache.org/email/). Both sit on top of [Jakarta Mail](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/) (previously JavaMail) and are very developer-friendly.

Answer (score 8):

for SMTP [subethasmtp](http://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/) rocks

Answer (score 4):

Maybe look at [Apache JAMES](http://james.apache.org/).

> The Apache JAMES Project delivers a rich set of open source modules and libraries, written in Java, related to internet mail and news which build into an advanced enterprise mail server.